# where is the most appropriate position for the adverb first?

Tags: adverbs

In the chemical process, **first** someone washes the wood, and then someone cuts it into small pieces in a chipping machine.

In the chemical process, someone washes the wood **first**, and then someone cuts it into small pieces in a chipping machine.

I am wondering if there is any difference between these sentences.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

> In the chemical process, **first** someone washes the wood, and then someone cuts it into small pieces in a chipping machine.

you are emphasizing the order of activities. In this example it is *first* and *then*.

When you write:

> In the chemical process, someone washes the wood **first**, and then someone cuts it into small pieces in a chipping machine.

you are emphasizing the activities happening to the wood. In this example it is *washes* and *cuts*.

More context is needed to really decide, but since you are describing a process order is probably more important.

Answer (score 0):

Putting *first* at the head of the clause is the better choice, as it emphasizes the (important) order of operations.

Answer (score -2):

I'd prefer:

> In the chemical process, someone **first** washes the wood ...